# Perform commands in Mac application sandbox?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, sandbox

I need my application to perform a command while in the Sandbox. This is the code I have so far:

```
// Set up the task
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/bash"];
NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-l",
                 @"-c",
                 @"rm -rf .Trash/*",
                 nil];
[task setArguments: args];

// Set the output pipe.
NSPipe *outPipe = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
[task setStandardOutput:outPipe];
[task launch];
```

I get a log output of:

> /bin/bash: /etc/profile: Operation not permitted

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Sudo commands are not allowed in sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to empty the trash then rather than trying to do it via brute force just let the Finder take care of it, e.g. using AppleScript:

```
tell application "Finder"
    empty trash
end tell
```

You can run AppleScript commands directly from Objective-C like this:

```
NSAppleScript *command = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"Finder\" to empty trash"];
[command executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

Comment: Nice idea but the AppleScript did not work. I got this log output:`NSAppleScriptErrorAppName = Finder;
    NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage = "Application isn\U2019t running.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorMessage = "Finder got an error: Application isn\U2019t running.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-600";
    NSAppleScriptErrorRange = "NSRange: {29, 11}";`

Comment: Odd - I tried it here first and it ran fine, but that was just in AppleScript Editor.

Comment: I think that the sandbox is the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I got it working! I just needed to add a temporary entitlement. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderMacLeod, how did you do that?